# Words to describe something that does not reach your expectations for it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Which word(s) would you use in a situation such as the one below, to make the sentence sound logical, natural and complete?

> You told me we were going to a nice park. We've spent almost two hours to get
>   here! And what do I see here? You call these three trees and two benches a park?! Are you kidding me? This is not a park, this is a ****_*__*_**** of a park!

Comment: What's the point of opening another question, essentially identical to your last one that has been closed, already knowing this will be closed too? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23165/kidnappers-wanted-to-determine-the-victims-what

Comment: @nico - "*What's the point of opening another question, essentially identical to your last one that has been closed*" - Shortly put, because I need to get an answer. If more expanded: yesterday I ran into that situation and didn't know how to say that in English. I stumbled exactly where the blank is (see my question). I need to know how to express that thought in English for the next time.

Comment: @brilliant: sure I understand you need an answer, but then just rephrase the question in another way, so that it will not be closed. By the way, I would use *a mockery of a park*, but I am not sure if that's what a native English speaker would say ;)

Comment: @nico - "*but then just rephrase the question in another way*" - I don't know how to rephrase my question better - I am not a native speaker either. What I wrote in my question is the best I can do. Can you, please, help me rephrase it?

Comment: The point is that is very very unlikely that anybody will ever find this question by searching for it (what would you look for). You could write: "What words would you use to describe something that does not at all reach the expectations you have for it?" You can then, if you wish, add the example of the park, maybe add another one or two examples. The question will be essentially the same, but it will be more wide and easier to look for. Also it may probably be more well suited for writers.stackexchange.com (I'm not sure)?

Comment: travesty, parody

Comment: @nico - "*The question will be essentially the same, but it will be more wide and easier to look for*" - Actually, I don't understand how would your suggested rephrasing not contradict the rules of this site in FAQ: "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page*". It seems that your rephrasing would make my question more open-ended, less practical and not really based on the actual problem. As for ability to search for my question, what do

Comment: @nico - we have tags for then? Will not those tags that I used in my question (word-choice, single-word-request,phrase-request) not be helpful in locating my question and other questions similar to mine?

Comment: @mplungjan - Thanks. You could make it into an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @brilliant: it's a question about English usage. I would be surprised if there was an English word specifically for a park which is not a park... and although the answer will help you it will not help other potential users as they will be really unlikely to be able to find the question as it is. And what about the time when you'll want to talk about a theater that is not a real theater or a castle which is merely a house or a fantastic restaurant which is just a takeaway? "Something that does not reach the expectations you have for it" sums them all up.

Comment: @brilliant: anyway, I may as well be wrong, so wait for a mod to show up, and see what they have to say about it. :)

Comment: @nico - I see, thank you. But here is the problem: before you gave me your suggested re-phrasing ("*What words would you use to describe something that does not at all reach the expectations you have for it?*") I didn't even know that I could generalize about my question in that way. Your command of English seems to be way better than mine. There are quite a few things that I have learned from your suggestion. For example, I didn't know that I could say "reach expectations" in English. In fact, I wouldn't even think of the word "expectation" as relevant to my situation. Perhaps, "anger"

Comment: @nico - would be the only word that would come across my mind. Providing the real context in my situation was the best way I could use to express what I meant. It's a kind of dilemma for me, I think: in order to describe my situation/problem properly here I need to know how to describe it properly in a more wide way, but in too wide a way (so that it would still be based on a practical situation) - it's quite a big task for a non-native speaker like me. In fact, I think, if somebody knows how to do that, then he probably also knows the answer to his question. It's like a paradox to me: if

Comment: @nico - you want to ask a question about English, you firstly need to know how to phrase your question in English properly. It's like if you want to learn how to swim, you need to get yourself enrolled in the "Shark" club, but the "Shark" club is located on a small island in the lake and there are no boats - the only way to get there is by swimming :). Perhaps, you are right about my question being more proper for writers.se, but I've always thought of that site as of the one for professional writers, and I, of course, am a far cry from them. You are right about waiting for the

Comment: @nico - moderators. I hope they will again show up here and shed some light on this situation. (Also hope they will not be angry at me and will not block me or do something that is done to bad users - I might have already "gotten" them with my previous question :) - I don't know if it's correct to say this way in English). Or maybe I could firstly consult with people on

Comment: @nico - meta about a question that I want to ask - as to whether the question that I am about to ask is okay to ask here and how to phrase it properly - and then, having received their approval, I would post my question. The thing is I have a big amount of questions similar to this one that I would want to ask here.

Comment: @brilliant: first of all bare in mind, I am not a native English speaker. Anyway when I said "it does not reach your expectations" I meant to say that you were expecting to see an enormous park and what you find were just two trees. In other words, you were expecting a lot and you didn't get half what you wanted. Anyway, I see you've got very good answers at the end :)

Comment: I think this question is way better worded and applicable to a much wider audience than that other one that got closed. (Also, it is applicable to a rather wide range of situations, not just parks.) However, "meta" stuff such as "this question will probably get killed" should be kept out of the body of the question, and I agree with @nico that it's generally not a good idea to just go ahead and post a question you don't deem on-topic yourself. When in doubt, ask in our chat first. This is also where lengthy discussions go. I reserve the right to clean up the comments without further notice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An epigone. IPA: ˈɛpɨɡəʊn  Greek: ἐπίγονοι

Epigone means a pathetic copy, a derivative, a completely un-memorable also-ran, created by the half-hearted effort of a talentless hack, who probably would never have had the idea to create the derivative work, if he had not admired the original. If "paragon" is the greatest exemplar of a particular platonic ideal, then the "epigone" is a shallow pale photocopy.  The greek root of the word epigone means "born later".  Synonyms: Also-Ran, Derivative.

I first saw the word referring to the "epigones of Tolkien"; That mass of drivel that copies Tolkien, poorly.

Comment: +1 for epigone! I sometimes read http://anepigone.blogspot.com/ epiwent, epigo, epigone! :) haha

Comment: did you actually click the up-vote button? :-)

Comment: I should credit China Miéville, author of Perdido Street Station for introducing me to the term.

Answer (score 6):

> a shadow of a park
>
> a semblance of a park
>
> a simulacrum of a park

Comment: Nice... or along the same lines, perhaps "an imitation of a park" :)

Comment: @psmears maybe you should add that as an answer? :) that's a good one actually! :)

Answer (score 5):

'Parody' would be my guess, FWIW.

Comment: Most people I know would just say "joke." It's a whole two syllables less!

Answer (score 5):

It won't fit exactly with the sentence, but I would use:

> "...this is a poor excuse for a park!"

Answer (score 4):

You could either say it is a *travesty* of a park or a *caricature* of a park.

From NOAD:

> **travesty** |ˈtravistē|
>   *noun* ( pl. -ties)
>   a false, absurd, or distorted representation of something : *the absurdly lenient sentence is a travesty of justice*.
>
> **caricature** |ˈkarikə ch ər; -ˌ ch oŏr|
>   *noun* ...
>   • a ludicrous or grotesque version of someone or something : *he looked like a caricature of his normal self*.

Answer (score 2):

So called. or Soi-Disant (french).

"This so-called park took us two hours to get to".

Comment: +1 @Warren how would you use soi-disant? "This soi-disant of a park took us two hours to get to?"

Comment: @PaulAmerigoPajo, use *[soi-disant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soi-disant#Adjective)* as an adjective; as in "This soi-disant park..."

Answer (score 1):

. . . embryo of a park!

. . . poor cousin of a park!

. . . back yard of a park!

. . .

Answer (score 0):

"Shit-hole" is the more forceful, but less "general audience" version.

I also agree with "joke", "tragedy", and "pathetic/sorry/poor excuse" (but follow that one with "for", not "of"). Those are things that a native English speaker (USA, anyway) would say.