# Something appears valuable or precious but it isn't, symbolically equivalent to Pyrite?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, symbols

I'm trying to think of a name for my new Animal Crossing town. I'm going for a city with grime and grit that isn't as gilded as some would think. There's a game with a town called Pyrite Town which works really well, and I'm trying to capture that vibe. Pyrite symbolizes something that is easily and commonly confused for something more valuable or precious, hence the nickname "Fool's gold".

I'm struggling to think of something that occupies a similar symbolic connotation. I thought of maybe a morel mushroom because they can be easily confused with poisonous variants or Morpho butterflies because they use refraction to fake their blue appearance without any blue pigment. Zirconium is similar because it can be confused with diamond, but none of these have the same instant association and history as pyrite.

Comment: (Not sure that the head honchos around here would consider literary names a kosher question). You have not really told us why pyrite is "symbolic".

Comment: @Lambie So it basically symbolizes something worthless being easily confused for something valuable or precious

Comment: This seems like a better fit for a sister site like https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ermanen I now agree with you, having seen the accepted answer.

Comment: Frank Sinatra - At Long Last Love, has a nice set of contrasting expressions. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rBvyBWnSTzQ

Comment: How about "tawdry" or "sequin"? Maybe Towndry or Sequincity.

Comment: Side Note: Zirconium is highly unlikely to be confused with diamond.  You are thinking of cubic zirconia, which is a zirconium-containing mineral.

Comment: I think "Fool's Gold" would be a fine name for a town, but this is an option you are already aware of.

Comment: Related question: [Word for the “fakeness” of extravagant places](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572724/word-for-the-fakeness-of-extravagant-places/572783#572783)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Tinsel* is a more common word which is symbolically equivalent to pyrite with its figurative usage; and it symbolizes something that appears valuable but is actually worthless. It comes from the fact that it is something glittering but cheap.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/202302?rskey=INMV9Q&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)* definition of the figurative sense of *tinsel*:

> *figurative.* Anything showy or attractive with little or no intrinsic worth; something that gives a deceptively fine or glittering appearance.

Even *Tinseltown* is used as a nickname for Hollywood because of the superficially glamorous world it represents.

Comment: [Tinsel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinsel) was originally made using silver, but a variety of metals have been used over the centuries, including gold and lead. Modern tinsel uses aluminium.

Comment: The association with Hollywood seems like it might undermine the OP's intended use.

Comment: @Barmar It is just an example how tinsel was already used to modify "town" as a nickname; as exactly how the OP wanted in a way the word can be used. However, the OP can use it with the meaning closer to the _OED_ definition, calling it "Tinsel City" for example.

Answer (score 11):

*Ersatz* means

> being a usually artificial and inferior substitute or imitation

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ersatz)

or

> ​artificial and not as good as the real thing or product

[OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ersatz)

*Ersatz City* has a nice ring to it, if that works.

Comment: Ersatzburg … or Pseudopolis!

Answer (score 5):

Building off of some of the words at [Word for the “fakeness” of extravagant places](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572724/word-for-the-fakeness-of-extravagant-places)

Tawdrytown

Giltberg

Glitzburg

Beaufaçade

Fauxville

Tackytown

Potemkinville

Veneer Village

Meretricity

Sham City

Painter's Folly

Comment: I like Fauxville!

Comment: @nigel222 It's a nice place to visit, but I wouldn't want to live there.

Comment: You suggest Glitzburg; that calls to mind Glitzville, which was used as the name of a city in Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking about [Talmi](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmi), but misremembered it being an English word, not a German one. But while looking up Talmi I came across two actual English words that might fit:

[Pinchbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinchbeck_%28alloy%29)

> (...) is a form of brass, an alloy of copper and zinc mixed in proportions so that it closely resembles gold in appearance. (...) Later dishonest jewellers passed pinchbeck off as gold; over the years the name came to mean a cheap and tawdry imitation of gold.

[Brummagem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brummagem) is one of the old local names of Birmingham (England).

> "Brummagem" and "Brummagem ware" are also terms for cheap and shoddy imitations, in particular when referring to mass-produced goods. This use is archaic in the UK, but persists in some specialist areas in the US and Australia.

(By the way, for those interested, Talmi is an alloy of copper and zinc. The idea is similar to pinchbeck).

Answer (score 4):

A ***Potemkin village*** is (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potemkin_village))

> Any construction (literal or figurative) whose sole purpose is to provide an external façade to a country that is faring poorly, making people believe that the country is faring better. The term comes from stories of a fake portable village built by Grigory Potemkin, former lover of Empress Catherine II, solely to impress the Empress during her journey to Crimea in 1787.

Modern historians believe this story is exaggerated, but the idea of a town that is "dressed up" to hide a shabbier reality fits somewhat with your description.  If you wanted a name that evoked this idea, you could call it "Potemkin City" or (sticking with the same linguistic roots) "Potemkingrad".

Comment: Very good find.  I knew about the movie "Battleship Potemkin" but didn't know about this usage.